# Create/Edit .doc .xls files on the iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ipad

I know .doc and .xls can be viewed using UIWebView but I want to make an App that will edit .doc and .xls files. could anyone enlighten me on how should I do this? or a library I can use or buy.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can utilize Googls docs api.

http://code.google.com/apis/documents/

http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/